# What is the correct way to apply a SpatialFilter on a Layer using GDAL & Python?

Tags: python, gdal, ogr, spatial-filter

I'm looking at Selecting those Polygons in One Shapefile which are contained inside the Polygon which is stored in another Shapefile.

I have managed to make some progress, and I have modified the sample given here: https://pcjericks.github.io/py-gdalogr-cookbook/layers.html#spatial-filter

I'm trying to figure out exactly what this function does, but the [documentation](http://gdal.org/python/osgeo.ogr.Layer-class.html#SetSpatialFilter) says that this might give incorrect results.

What the correct way to apply a SpatialFilter on a Layer using GDAL & Python?

Answer (score 3):

Using `ogr2ogr` ([`gdal.VectorTranslate`](http://gdal.org/python/osgeo.gdal-module.html#VectorTranslate)) as library function:

```
from osgeo import gdal

ds_in = gdal.OpenEx('/path/to/input.shp')
ds_out = gdal.VectorTranslate('/path/to/output.shp', ds_in,
                             format = 'ESRI Shapefile',
                             spatFilter = [479609, 4764629, 479764, 4764817])
```

where `spatFilter` is the spatial filter as `(minX, minY, maxX, maxY)` bounding box.